# Does an implicit Runge Kutta scheme applied on a nonlinear ODE give a nonlinear set of equations to solve in each step?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, differential-equations

We want to approximately solve an ODE
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y,t)$$
with the Runge Kutta method
$$y_{n+1} = y_n + h \sum_{i=1}^s b_i k_i$$
$$k_i = f\left(y_n + h \sum_{j=1}^s a_{ij} k_j,\,t_n + c_i h\right)$$

For explicit methods the matrix $a$ is strictly lower triangular and thus you can determine $k_i$ explicitly without solving any set of equations.
For implicit methods on the other hand, $a$ is not lower triangular and calculating $k_i$ becomes more complicated since you have to solve a set of equations.

I was of the impression that for implicit RK methods you would have to solve a linear set of equations, but looking at the definition of $k_i$ it looks to me as if $f(y,t)$ is nonlinear the system of equations determining $k_i$ will also be nonlinear. Is this correct?

If so, does this render implicit RK methods quite useless for nonlinear $f(y,t)$s because of the heavy computational power required to solve the nonlinear equationset?

For more background on RK methods take a look at:
[List of RK methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#3.2F8-rule_fourth-order_method), [RK methods in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem with implicit schemes (any kind of schemes) applied for the solution of nonlinear equations. You do need to solve a nonlinear equation (or even worse, a nonlinear system) at each step, and usually this done with Newton's method. There are also hybrid methods, implicit-explicit, where the implicit corresponds to the linear part and the explicit to the nonlinear one. (See for exmple the works of Ascher, Ruuth et al.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a research-level question; the answers can be found in any undergraduate text on the subject.

> it looks to me as if f(y,t) is nonlinear the system of equations determining ki will also be nonlinear. Is this correct?

Yes.

> If so, does this render implicit RK methods quite useless for nonlinear f(y,t)s because of the heavy computational power required to solve the nonlinear equationset?

No.